# Updating models with unique fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I get a "value already exists" error when I try to update the existing record.

example: I have 10 Companies in a database. Now I want to edit the 4th record. Am looking to update the company "short_name" and leaving the "full_name" unchanged. When I hit submit, an error message is displayed in postman for full_name field "Already Exist" How can I avoid this?

*Model.py*

```py
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    id                  = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, 
                                            editable=False, 
                                            primary_key=True,
                                            verbose_name='ID',)

    short_name           = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                                            null=True, 
                                            blank=True,)

    full_name            = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
                                            unique = True,)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.full_name)
```

*Serializers.py*

```py
class RegisterationCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    short_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=CompanyProfile.objects.all(),
                                    message="Short Name already exists or already in use")],
    )

    full_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=CompanyProfile.objects.all(),
                                    message="Full Name already exists or already in use")],
    )
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'short_name': {'required': True},
            'full_name': {'required': True},
        }
```

*views.py*

```py
class MainCompanyProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset            = CompanyProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = RegisterationCompanySerializer
    permission_classes  = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def update(self, request, pk=id ,*args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile, id = pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

*urls.py*

```py
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('', MainCompanyProfileView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

*Stacktrace*
**Note**: There are a lot of fields in each company have made an example to sort this out
*Now when I update the short_name leaving full_name unchanged*

```py
> company/views.py(56)update()
-> partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
(Pdb) n
> company/views.py(57)update()
-> instance = get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile, id = pk)
(Pdb) n
> /views.py(58)update()
-> serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
(Pdb) instance
<CompanyProfile: Test Company>
(Pdb) n
> company/views.py(59)update()
-> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
(Pdb) n
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: { 'full_name': [ErrorDetail(string='Full Name already exists or already in use', code='unique')]}
> company/views.py(59)update()
-> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

*Validation error*

```py
'full_name': [ErrorDetail(string='Full Name already exists or already in use', code='unique')]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually found the mistake that I was sending all the data in the postman together that is the reason it suggested the `full name already exists` so for the update I only required to send the data for field that needs to be updated.

Other Mistakes

1. I should have removed `unique=True` from models.py as I already been doing in serializers.py
2. In views.py update function was not required as its using `updateMixin` which is already written and was working well

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `Patch` method instead of `PUT` method to update specific fields only.

Comment: Yes, that's whats I did forget to mention thanks @Harshit